# How to install a local repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I upgraded to Eclipse 4.5 from 4.4.2 today (Windows, JRE 1.8 64-bit). However, my CVS plugin is completely broken.

I'm getting the following error messages in the logs:

```
org.eclipse.team.core.TeamException: Could not instantiate provider org.eclipse.team.cvs.core.cvsnature for project plugins.
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapNewProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.mapExistingProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider.getProvider(RepositoryProvider.java:507)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

followed by

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui/icons/full/eview16/repo_rep.gif".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:215)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

What can I do to get my Eclipse installation to attach to CVS again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new version of Eclipse does not include the CVS features. In the Mars (4.5) release, CVS capability was removed from most (all?) of the Eclipse packages.

You can install the CVS features manually via **Help** > **Install new software...** and selecting the Mars repository. See [this wiki page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm) for more detailed instructions.